# OpenLayers Javascript, Large Resolution Map disappears until zoomed in

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm loading a map in Openlayers (JavaScript) that has a high resolution. (9149 by 7700)

When I load the page it appears blank (all controls/map/everything is missing) until I zoom in. I'm curious what would be causing this and how I might be able to resolve this.
I've pasted some of my code below that should hopefully shed some light on the issue (or what I'm missing).

```
function initMap() {

OpenLayers.ImgPath = "Openlayers/img/";
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);
var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
var graphic = new OpenLayers.Layer.Image('Foo', 'images/LargeMap.jpg',
new OpenLayers.Bounds(2616634.1736111115, 179682.0532407412, 2625783.173611111,187382.0532407412),
new OpenLayers.Size(9149,7700), { isBaseLayer: true });
```

and

```
var options = {
zoom: 5,
theme: null,
projection: PASouthPlane,
displayProjection: PASouthPlane,
units: "ft",
resolutions: [19.1088,9.5544,4.7772,2.3886, 1.19432, 0.5971, 0.29855, 0.149275],
scales:[54168,27084,13542,6771,3385.5, 1692.75, 846.375, 423.1875],
//resolutions: [4.7772,2.3886, 1.19432, 0.5971, 0.29855, 0.149275],
//scales:[13542,6771,3385.5, 1692.75, 846.375, 423.1875],
//maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-8.39794e+006, 4.83761e+006, -8.394873e+006, 4.840365e+006) //-8.39802e+006, 4.83753e+006, -8.39479e+006, 4.84045e+006
maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(2616634.1736111115, 179682.0532407412, 2625783.173611111,187382.0532407412)
};
```

--

```
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:2272"] = "+proj=lcc +lat_1=40.96666666666667 +lat_2=39.93333333333333 +lat_0=39.33333333333334 +lon_0=-77.75 +x_0=600000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192 +no_defs";
var PASouthPlane = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:2272");
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the initial center and zoom of the map at the end of you initMap function. map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);

Comment: I tried adding that, but zooming out (which I need to see most or all of the map) still makes all controls and the map disappear.

Comment: I guess it is a bit hard to come up with a jsFiddle given the large external image?

Comment: I'll see if I can give that a shot. I'm willing to try anything

Comment: At least a full working (not working) example, if you see what I mean. I can always create a large image myself locally.

Comment: Drop the maxExtent and set baseLayer false, try to repro.  Also, are the Bounds you defined for the image below the max resolution you gave the map options?  That may get you to the place you describe.